# If I save seeds from sweet million cherry tomatoes will I get more sweet million tomatoes

Tags: tomatoes, seeds

If I save seeds from sweet million cherry tomatoes will I get more sweet million tomatoes?

The seeds say they are hybrid seeds.

Comment: are they pollinated from ONLY that type of plant, or are they getting cross pollinated with other species?

Comment: You can find stabilized versions of it that breed true, but in all likelihood, they'll say they're open-pollinated and not say hybrid (and definitely won't say F1 hybrid).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sweet Million are an F1 variety, so will not come true. Seeds saved from their first year may grow what are known as F2 types, which may be quite close to the original F1 Sweet Million, but any seed saved from the second year will produce random tomatoes. More info here http://www.gardenfocused.co.uk/vegetable/tomato-outdoor/variety-sweet-million.php

Answer (score 3):

Sweet Million is one of the more stable hybrid cherry tomatoes I've ever collected seeds from. It will do excellent as a F-2 AND F-3 plants. As a matter of fact, our F-3 plants produced the best tasting cherries. But this could have been because of the growing season. PS-- Collect and try them for yourself. Don't take anyone's word about anything, when It comes to tomatoes. Collect plenty of seeds because if you don't, you will wish you had of.

Comment: I had (this was 3 years ago) and it turned out ok.